# How do I disable HTML frames in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, html

I can't find any settings to allow me to disable the display of HTML Frames in my browser. If there is no setting is some sort of extension my only option?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to test your web page for very very very old browsers? If you disable frames, what do you expect to see in the browser? One of the frames only? Nothing? Are you sure you mean frames?

Comment: I am quite sure I mean frames. And yes, I intend to test the output of a website when frames are disabled or not allowed.

Comment: Fair enough, from a developer's point of view I can understand it, from an end user's it would just be weird in 2013 :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think there is a setting for this. The last browsers where I saw such an option was some version of Opera.

In principle, it should be possible by using the following CSS code as a user style sheet:

```
frame { display: none !important; }
noframes { display: block !important; }
```

But it seems that it does not work: Chrome recognizes the rules, but fails to obey them.

Comment: We can set browser.frames.enabled to false in FireFox about:config

Comment: @Pacerier, that’s interesting, but the setting seems to just make a frameset page look empty – it does *not* cause the `noframes` element to be rendered!

Comment: Odd that chrome doesn't have this option or something similar.